# OpenVPN service fails to start

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am trying to set up a VPN server on a Raspberry Pi, however, I get an error `[FAIL] Starting virtual private network daemon: server failed!`

I have followed a few different tutorials, but none of them end up in a working service. I'm sure I have miss-interpreted an instruction somewhere, but can anyone help me get it working?

The Pi is running Raspbian. It has a static IP 192.168.1.230. The router is 192.168.1.254.

My /etc/openvpn/server.conf file reads:

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
user nobody
group nogroup
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
client-to-client
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
log-append /var/log/openvpn
comp-lzo
```

ifconfig -a shows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:78:40:2b  
          inet addr:192.168.1.230  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18862 errors:0 dropped:35 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1130316 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:1997172 (1.9 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

/var/log/openvpn contains:

```
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 OpenVPN 2.2.1 arm-linux-gnueabihf [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Oct 12 2013
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 WARNING: --keepalive option is missing from server config
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 NOTE: your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet address 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conflicts if you connect to the VPN server from $
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.1.254
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.8.0.1 pointopoint 10.8.0.2 mtu 1500
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 /sbin/route add -net 10.8.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.2
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 GID set to nogroup
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 UID set to nobody
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
Fri Jul  4 18:32:39 2014 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

**Update 13 Jul 14**

The command `ps aux | grep openvpn` shows:

```
nobody    2269  0.0  0.2   5072  1192 ?        Ss   Jul04   0:17 /usr/sbin/openvpn --writepid /var/run/openvpn.openvpn.pid --daemon ovpn-openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf
root      5140  0.0  0.1   3548   800 pts/0    S+   08:54   0:00 grep openvpn
```

The command `netstat -l | grep 1194` has no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log output and the fact that the tun device is showing up in `ifconfig` suggests that the openvpn daemon is indeed running. Can you see it in the process list if you run:

```
ps aux | grep openvpn
```

The service start command, are you running that as sudo/root? If not, it may be attempting to adjust routing tables or control the tun device, and it doesn't have the adequate permissions.

Also, make sure that:

```
netstat -l | grep 1194
```

Shows the daemon listening on UDP port 1194

The log output shows that the openvpn daemon has been able to create the tun device (and it's showing up in the output of ifconfig), so I'd be very surprised if the daemon isn't actually running. If that is the case, and you're not sudo'ing the service control, there may be something up with the init script.

Comment: I ran the commands you mentioned and updated my post above with the results. I did `sudo` the restart commands (and tried as SU), as well as get the error messages on boot.

Comment: It's possible that there is an entry in /etc/services for openvpn, in which case `netstat -l | grep 1194` wouldn't show the port listening, because it would show the service name (not port number). Try again with `netstat -ln | grep 1194` - the `n` switch stops resolution of naming to services and DNS.

Comment: You can troubleshoot the daemon startup failure by adding a `-x` to the shebang line at the top of the script:
`#!/bin/bash -x` ... or if it's a sh script instead of bash - `#!/bin/sh`

Once you've done that, when you run `/etc/init.d/openvpn start` it should be more descriptive about where the failure is occuring

Comment: Turns out that OpenVPN was failing due to two .conf files in the /etc/openvpn folder. It must have gotten confused between the two. Deleting the 'example' file and leaving mine results in the service starting ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, glad to hear it's sorted :) It was probably trying to start two daemons both listening on port 1194. Having multiple config files is supported, but they need to differ on certain specifics; most commonly the clash is to do with daemons trying to start on the same listening port.